# Play audio file on the server side using ElFinder

Tags: javascript, php, elfinder

I am trying to play an .mp3 file on the server side using ElFinder.
I have created two instances of ElFinder.
How should I play a file from one of the instances on the server side?
Here is the code

```
handlers : {
                            select : function(event, elfinderInstance) {
                                var selected = event.data.selected; 

                    if (selected.length>0) {
                    var filenamex=elfinderInstance.file(selected[0]).name;
                    console.log(filenamex);

                    var path=elfinderInstance.path(selected[0]);
                    console.log(path);
                    if(filenamex.indexOf(".mp3") == filenamex.length - 4) {
                     console.log("Mp3 file");
                    }
                    }           
                    }
                        },
                lang : 'en',
                customData : {answer : 42},
                rememberLastDir :false,
                debug:true


             }).elfinder('instance');
```

I first try to check whether the selected file is a mp3 file or not.
If it is a mp3 file then I should be able to play it.

Comment: Dont you mind posting your code?

Comment: You can’t play an MP3 file server-side. If it was playing on the server, the client (the person viewing your web page) wouldn’t be able to hear it!